# How does recursion know when to stop?

Tags: c++, recursion

Why does this work:

```
void reversal(string x, int y){
       if (x[y] == '\0'){
       } else {
            reversal(x,y+1);
            cout << x[y];
       }
    }
```

And this doesnt?:

```
 void reversal(string x, int y){
        reversal(x,y+1);
        cout << x[y];
 }
```

Why doesn't the loop repeat forever (even though it doesn't do anything past the string size). Is a blank 'if' statement the way to end recursive functions?

Comment: a deterministic recursive function always needs an independent value for at least one of its variables.

Comment: Recursion need a base case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blank if statement in the first code snippet is what we call a **base case**.

Base cases are very important and usually the first thing in any recursive method as a matter of style and readability. The essential thing to take away is that each call to the recursive method does some small amount of work but it has to eventually receive input which causes it to stop recursing. In your example it simply stops once it reaches a base case but often base cases will return some value which previous invocations will then combine.

For example, a method which finds the latest (i.e. closest to z) letter in a string might recurse on both halves of the string, returning either the latest from the first half or the latest from the second. The recursive calls keep breaking the smaller substrings in half until it reaches a base case, a single letter which just gets returned to the previous calls. The later letters will bubble up through the recursive calls until finally the first invocation will return the later from the two halves of the original string.

Answer (score 0):

because in the first, the if condition doesn't do anything, it just returns, it doesn't call reversal again, so the function returns, then it backs out to the next function which now reutnrs etc etc,

the other one just keeps calling reversal and never has a condition that doesn't do anything but call reversal.

Answer (score 0):

The first one stops when it reaches the end of the string (if the next character in the string is the null terminator, "\0").

The second one never checks, runs off of the end of the string, and breaks.